# OpenVPN to only access remote server resources

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, split-tunnel

I have set up OpenVPN server on a CentOS 8 machine in the office, wanting to access the server from home. I have noticed though that *all* internet traffic is being routed through then VPN. Ideally from home my internet access would be direct, and only when office based resources are required, to use the VPN connection. I have been reading about split tunneling, but don't yet know whether it is a server or client side option, or how to do it at all. Is split tunneling what I am looking for?

How can my ultimate objective be achieved?

Comment: avoid `redirect-gateway`, add necessary routes; whether it's server side or client side depends on your configuration; some GUI client app/program might add redirect-gateway itself, so I heard, so at least check their settings

Comment: The server configuration contains the line `push "redirect-gateway defl bypass-dhcp"`. Is a `push` something that the server instructs the client to do?

Comment: Yes. You probably want to start from removing that line. Then you would want to figure out the destination IP blocks that leads to your "office based resources" and add them with the `route` directive (with `push` if configured from the server side). Check the route table on the VPN server to get some hints.

Comment: "Check the route table on the VPN server to get some hints." Is there an explicit table definition or is this essentially a runtime thing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What I meant was if you can access those "resources" on that server, whoever set it up have configured routes that are necesary, and you just need to push those destinations as routes to the clients. (It could be only the subnet the server itself is in though, depending on the scale of your company and etc.) Make sure your home LAN subnet doesn't conflict with any of your office's, otherwise it would be a bit tricky.

Comment: So the office subnet route seems to be working, but removing the `redirect-gateway` has not worked so well. The local internet/network connection is not working despite having been given a DHCP address.

Answer (score 1):

In the case I have presented, three things were required of the VPN server configuration.

1) Eliminate the gateway redirect

```
;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

2) Create a specific route to the office subnet

```
push "route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0"
```

3) Disable the push of DNS servers, in this configuration Google's IPv4 addresses:

```
;push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
;push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

Credit to @Tom Yan in the comments in arriving at this solution.